# Matching text against table of names

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best way to quickly check a long string of text against a MySQL table of names, to see if any of the names are contained within the text?

Comment: have you got any example code on the approach you've tried so far Will?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/String/Patternmatchstringcontains.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE name LIKE = '%name%'
```

OR (fulltext)

```
MATCH... AGAINST
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at this tutorial [link](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlwhere.php)

I like myself using `LIKE % %` query

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should organise your string into an array of names, this way its more manageable when it come's to checking against a data source.

you should look at mysql `LIKE` or `IN` commands, used like so:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column LIKE (params)
```

if you had the string:

```
$string = "tom paul james robert yes123";
```

you can use php functions to prepare it so you can do:

```
$string = explode(" ",$names);
$string = implode(",",$string);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (".$string.")";
```

With the `LIKE` command you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%robert%' OR column LIKE '%yes123%'
```